# Javascript: is it safe to assign the result of array.filter() to the same array

Tags: javascript

Is it *officially* safe to:

```
someArray = someArray.filter(function(item) {
              return item !== 'something';
            });
```

I mean assigning back to the same array the filter function is called for, in one line.
And same question for all other array prototype functions that return an array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe because it's returning the value from the function.

You should be careful about making sure you're reusing it correctly, though.

Comment: what happens if we not assign again to someArray?